# HTML page to list and display images locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This is probably a very simple thing to do but its been so long since I've done anything web based I don't know where to start so thought I'd ask you helpful peoples in the hope someone might know of a good example somewhere online I can plunder for ideas.

I have a folder full of images, I want to create a html page that has a list of said images on the right and a number of panels/spaces those images can go on the left, users can then drag from the list into the panels and the images would be displayed.  Users could then drag images off to remove them (a right click option would also be fine) or drag other images in to replace them.

I'm sure this kind of thing could be done in jquery but I've no clue where to start, anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything so far??

Comment: This is not a problem you are stucked with, this sounds like a job for a freelancer.

Comment: Could possibly be its a freelance job, although it's more a personal project and nothing I would want to spend money on. I've not tried anything yet mostly because I have literally no idea where to start so I guess I just need to rely more on google than asking here initially...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? this will make it draggable in jquery. However this will be needed with plug-ins.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("Insert ID or CLASS").draggable();
});
</script>
```

However in order to prevent your draggable class or ID to be dragged everywhere you could use something like this:

```
$(function() { $( "ID OR CLASS" ).draggable({ containment: "window" }); });
```

Read the API https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment for more info.

This is how you can drop something in jquery:

```
$("ID OR CLASS").droppable();
```

I recommend you to use a `toggle()` on the classes when you dragg them to a div. So when you drop a class the image will be dropped instead of the div.

I hope this helped enough to give you a start with jquery. Although the question was very unclear and I hope you will edit the question to a bit more usefull one (So others can also benefit from it), I still wish you the best!

Comment: Thankyou that does help me, sorry my question was a bit vague, I guess I'm not very sure what it is I even want to achieve myself beyond the high level finished result   I'll have a bit more of a stab and then update once things get clearer 